# How to measure code performance in a multi threaded application?

Tags: java, multithreading, performance

I am currently working on a project where in a am not using any performance measurement tools to calculate the time it takes for the code to execute.

Instead i am using `long  <variableName> = System.nanoTime();` at the start and end of the code, and subtracting them to get the time it takes to complete the execution.

It was working fine until i started to use it in a multi threaded code.

```
public class DataEntry {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        long l = System.nanoTime();

        /*
        *  Regular Multithreading code to generate 'n' number of threads to
        *  perform a certain task.
        */


        System.out.println("Total Execution Time Is : "+((System.nanoTime()-l)/1000000.0)+" milli seconds");
    }
}
```

The problem i am facing here is that my `main()` thread finishes executing long before the user created threads have finished their tasks.

What i mean is, i get an output something like this...

```
Total Execution Time Is : 9.600147 milli seconds
Thread#1 :  Execution Over Bye Bye
Thread#2 :  Execution Over Bye Bye
Thread#3 :  Execution Over Bye Bye
Thread#4 :  Execution Over Bye Bye
Thread#5 :  Execution Over Bye Bye
```

> All the ***child*** threads give their corresponding final o/p
>   couple of seconds after `main()` has finished executing

I understand that all threads run independently of one another and that we can make main sleep() till all the ***child*** threads finish their executions.

I was wondering if there is a way to do it in such a way that would allow me to prevent any thread from waiting for one another, such that the last thread that is finishing its execution is responsible to return me the final execution time.

Following is the code

> DataEntry.java

```
public class DataEntry {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        long l = System.nanoTime();

//STRING THAT WILL BE USED TO DOWNLOAD THE MULTIPLE FILES

        String[] strDownload = {"https://unsplash.com/photos/n61ur6rT_F8/download?force=true",
                    "https://unsplash.com/photos/GLS3mY37RPo/download?force=true",
                    "https://unsplash.com/photos/v6asLq_dYzw/download?force=true",
                    "https://unsplash.com/photos/ePB2oGU8mb4/download?force=true",
                    "https://unsplash.com/photos/yEHQfGNKnZ4/download?force=true"};


        //CREATE A FIXED NUMBER OF THREADS BASED ON THE LENGTH OF THE INPUT STRING ARRAY
            for (int i = 0; i < strDownload.length; i++) {
                Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadsGeneration(strDownload[i]));   //PASSING THE i'th ELEMENT OF THE ARRAY AS THE PARAMETER FOR THE CONSTRUCTOR
                t.start();                                                      //CREATE THE THREAD
                System.out.println(t.getName()+"\n");

            }

            System.out.println("Total Execution Time Is : "+((double)(System.nanoTime()-l)/1000000)+" milli seconds");
        }
    }
```

> ThreadGeneration.java

```
public class ThreadsGeneration implements Runnable{

    private static String string;

    public ThreadsGeneration(String string) {
        ThreadsGeneration.string = string;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Inside RUN");
        DownloadManager.getData(string);

    }   
}
```

> DownloadManager.java

```
public class DownloadManager {


    public static void getData(String strDownload) {


        String strDestination = "C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\"+Math.random()+".jpg";

        try {       

            printData(strDownload,strDestination);

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static synchronized void printData(String strDownload, String strDestination) throws Exception {

        URL url = new URL(strDownload);
        ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(strDestination);
        fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
        fos.close();
        rbc.close();
        System.out.println("Everything done");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you just do the timing outside the launching and joining of the threads?

Comment: The simple answer is to keep the main thread alive until the end by making a while loop that scans a pool of threads, and only when all of them are closed then return the time. There is no harm in keeping the main thread alive.

Comment: Maybe be a bit more specific what you are trying to measure. I don't think it's 100% clear atm

Comment: One option is to use `CountDownLatch` to wait

Comment: @user7 could you please elaborate and, if possible, give a sample code?

Comment: I meant - to make the main thread wait for the other threads to finish, you could use it (or use the normal `join` method on the threads if you actually have the reference to the threads). We are not sure how you create the threads, so it is difficult to answer and hence I suggested that

Comment: @user7 here is the whole thing. Now please elaborate your `CountDownLatch`

Comment: Since you have the reference to the threads, you could add them to a list (or an array) and call `join` on them for the main thread to wait for their completion

Answer (score 3):

Two ways I can think of:

1. Join all the threads with main thread by calling `.join()` and then print out the time all the threads took to join. That way, the main thread will easily print the time it took.

   Main doesn't sleep in this case. It just waits.
2. Have your threads print the time they took, at the end of the code they run. That way you can see the individual time of each thread, and spend some brain cycles on computing the overall execution time yourself.